# MLflow stores tags but does not return them

Tags: mlflow

I am running the below code to store tags and then to retrieve them. As you can see below, Mlflow is storing one set of tags and returning another.

```
import mlflow
with mlflow.start_run() as active_run:
    tw = { "run_id": 1}
    mlflow.set_tags(tw)            
    print("Tags are ", active_run.data.tags)
    print(type(active_run.data.tags))
```

Output

```
Tags are  {'mlflow.source.name': '/media/Space/AI/anaconda4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py', 'mlflow.source.type': 'LOCAL', 'mlflow.user': 'adeel'}
```

Looking at the stored tags through mlflow ui, I can see that the tag "run_id" set by the code is actually stored in the run. However, only the header information of the run seems to be getting returned by active_run.data.tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, you have to query your run again in MLflow to get the run with all the info that you logged. In the example below, I call `mlflow.get_run(<run_id>)` to achieve this.

```
import mlflow


with mlflow.start_run() as active_run:
  tags = { "my_tag": 1}
  mlflow.set_tags(tags)            
  # Keep track of the run ID of the active run
  run_id = active_run.info.run_id

run = mlflow.get_run(run_id)
print("The tags are ", run.data.tags)
```